# Jenkins - No valid crumb was included in request

Tags: jenkins, tomcat, csrf, http-status-code-403, tomcat9

Jenkins - `2.263.1(LTS)` deployed through `tomcat` on `CentOS-8.2`and have `Nginx reverse proxy` running in-front of Jenkins.

Under `Manage Jenkins` > `Configure Systems` - `Apply` and `Save` not working, Due to this error, i cannot `Apply` (or) `Save` any of my configurations, It always shows below error on browser (Firefox & Chrome).

> HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Message No valid crumb was included in the request
>
> Description The server understood the request but refuses to authorize
> it. Apache Tomcat/9.0.30

Also `Jenkins` > `Manage Jenkins` > `Configure Global Security` - `Apply` works. But `Save` not working this too results same above given error.

`Systems log` error message.

> Feb 19, 2021 10:56:05 AM WARNING hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter
> doFilter No valid crumb was included in request for
> /jenkins/configSubmit by ankit.sahu. Returning 403.

**Workaround tried:-**

```
1) Under Configure Global security > CSRF Protection > Enable proxy compatibility( Tick marked Enabled). - Didn't work so disabled with below command.
2) hudson.security.csrf.GlobalCrumbIssuerConfiguration.DISABLE_CSRF_PROTECTION = true - Even this didn't solve the problem.
3) Installed the Strict Crumb Issuer plugin.
   Enabled this plugin and unchecked Check the session ID from its configuration (Under Jenkins Configure Global Security).
4) Restated the Jenkins.
```

Even tried by adding below in `/apache-tomcat-9.0.30/conf/tomcat-users.xml` file.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
    <role rolename="manager-status"/>
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <role rolename="admin-script"/>
    <user username="user" password="password" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,admin-gui,admin-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

However still experiencing same problem. I don't know how to fix it, Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

You can (temporarily) disable CSRF with below groovy script. Go to `Manage Jenkins >> Script Console`, then execute the below groovy script.

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def instance = Jenkins.instance
instance.setCrumbIssuer(null)
```

Comment: Hope this will help [Navigation in Jenkins fails with 'No valid crumb was included in request' errors](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039598171-Navigation-in-Jenkins-fails-with-No-valid-crumb-was-included-in-request-errors?mobile_site=true#:~:text=If%20changing%20the%20proxy%20configuration,Configure%20Global%20Security%20%3E%20CSRF%20Protection) Also, after applying the fix try to remove the cookies of browser and log back in Jenkins.

Comment: 1) `Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security > CSRF Protection
Tick the Enable proxy compatibility option` 2) Restated the Jenkins and cleared the browser cookies and tried same error shown, Also tried `Jenkins Location Jenkins URl - http://jenkins-server:8080/jenkins` updated in `JENKINS_HOME/config.xml` file. 4) On browser `http://jenkins-server:8080/jenkins` -> Configure systems still not able to appy of save. same error shows.

Comment: Check this out https://issues.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-46986

Comment: Yes Since i have reverse proxy so under `Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security > CSRF Protection Tick the Enable proxy compatibility option` enabled this and tried still resulting same problem. even it doesn't work without reverse proxy as well `http://jenkins-server:8080/jenkins`

Comment: I have debugged today and found it is not a plugin issue. It is due to security update (CSRF) festure implementation in recent versions  so in my case it hosted through apache tomcat. So how do I resolve this? Your inputs ll be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The nonces embedded into web output from Jenkins with CSRF protection are based (at least in part as I've read) on values from the requesting client. In addition to making sure your reverse proxy is correctly configured to pass X-Forwarded-For and X-Forwarded-Proto, make sure that Tomcat valve is in place to expose those header values in the servlet request API so Jenkins has access to them.

Add the following to `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml`, subordinate to the `<Host>` element:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for" protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto" />
```

ref: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/reverse-proxy-configuration-troubleshooting/ 
ref: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/reverse-proxy-configuration-with-jenkins/ 
ref: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_IP_Valve

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `jenkinsapi`, I resolved this error by specifying `useCrumb=True` in the constructor:

```
j = Jenkins(base_url, username=username, password=password, useCrumb=True)
```